# convert a string (such as 9 A.M. - 1 P.M.) to two integers (such as 9 and 13) in swift

Tags: swift, time

I am currently working on an app that has the user input times in a form such as 2 A.M. - 5 P.M.

Is there any way to take that string and convert it to two integers in military time such as 2 and 17?

Comment: What have you tried?  Many good programmers here will help you with programming.  Fewer will be a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just split this String using componentsSeparatedByString, convert those 2 Strings to NSString and extract a integerValue from each of them. You will need also to add 12 hours to the result if it is less then 12. You will need also to return 0 in case of 12am.:

```
extension String {
    var hour:Int {
        var result = (self as NSString).integerValue
        if contains(Array(lowercaseString).map{String($0)}, "p") {
            result = result < 12 ? result + 12 : result
        } else {
            result = result == 12 ? 0 : result
        }
        return result
    }
    var hours:(from:Int, to:Int) {
        return (componentsSeparatedByString("-").first!.hour,componentsSeparatedByString("-").last!.hour)
    }
}
```

testing

```
let timeInput1 =  "2 A.M. - 5 P.M."
let timeInput2 = "9 A.M. - 1 P.M."

timeInput1.hours       // (.0 2, .1 17)
timeInput1.hours.from  // 2
timeInput1.hours.to    // 17

timeInput2.hours       // (.0 9, .1 13)
timeInput2.hours.from  // 9
timeInput2.hours.to    // 13
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "5AM"
var output = Int()

var firstCharacterOfString = input[advance(input.startIndex, 0)]
        //search string for first character, return char 
var characterToString:String = String(firstCharacterOfString)
        //convert char to String
var StringToIntegar:Int = characterToString.toInt()!
        //convert String to Int

if input.rangeOfString("PM") != nil{
        //if input has "PM" in it perform this code
    output = StringToIntegar + 12}
        //add 12 to Int

else {//if input DOESN'T have "PM" in it perform this code
    output = StringToIntegar}
```

NOTE: won't work for 10,11,12 since only searching for first character